# Ubuntu hangs frequently

Tags: 12.04

I have an Athlon x2 7750, 2GB RAM and I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on 8Gb moser baer pen drive.

Software I installed are: apache2, php5, mysql-server, mysql-workbench, komodo-edit, anjuta. I also wanted gimp but I stopped.

Problem is Ubuntu stops responding after 3-4 minute and start responding again for 3-4 minutes. and this continues. I'm use Windows 7 and do not know much about Linux, I wanted to install it on my hard disk.

Can community help me on how to get smooth Ubuntu???

Answer (score 2):

**its a problem of memory**

make sure you have a Swap Partition twice the size of your RAM

how to make swap partition
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

Answer (score -1):

You installed Ubuntu on a Pen Drive?

Pen drives are not fast or robust enough to run an OS off. That is probably why your Ubuntu keeps hanging every now and then.

You need to install Ubuntu on your Hard Disk or at least on a USB HD (not recommended).

The procedure for doing this is quite standard. You can follow the guide on the official site.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-desktop

Comment: I've run Ubuntu from pendrives (and CD's and DVD's) for weeks straight without rebooting, installing packages, running servers, logging out and back in, and I haven't observed such systems being less stable than an installed system.

Comment: Eliah Kagan, here is what is did:-
1) I created bootabe live ubuntu pendrive with grub
2) after booting i deleted c partition that ugly buggy 7
3) i installed xp again to make my old ntfs data accessible
4) i created a 39gb ext3 partition at the end of my segate 500gb hd
5) i created 1 gb linux swap prtn
6) i started the ubuntu installer
7) followed the instructions
8) left my desk for 50-55 mins, as waiting for me is bad
9) ubuntu was installed
thnks